# Email is aleady registered when login using WP Social Login

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, plugins

I mostly work on ASP.NET Applications but first time i tried with Wordpress to get user login with facebook and gmail with WP Social Login Plugin and storing personel information i.e user name, first name, email , age etc into database table and i successfully did this and now the problem is if a user is logged in with facebook we have his/her email in our database and when the same user try to login with google then plugin checks if email is in database or not and if yes it shows errors "Email already Exists" but we want to login a user using both facebook and gmail account at any cost no matter email can be same for both facebook and gmail account.
here is [link](http://onlinedoctorfinder.com/?page_id=5) to see the problem. If you have same email with your facebook and google account then you can see the error easily and suggest me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress by default only allows one account per email address [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-multiple-accounts/) allows you to amend that to many, which is a work around. To actual 100% meet your requirements I would contact the author of the plugin or write on the support page of the plugin [here](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/oa-social-login)

Comment: i have installed your suggested plugin to unlimit multilple accounts for wordpress but its not working for me any more, so what i should do now? do i need to customize WP Social Login myself to unlimit the number of accounts with same email? or please suggest me easy way.

Comment: I would then check the plugin for existance of this function . https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/email_exists and stop it from checking.

Comment: so do you want me to modift wp social login plugin and then use it ? with change in function reference?